# Create listener for CustomComponent in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, observer-pattern, vaadin7

I'm trying to create a `CustomComponent` in vaadin 7. The component has a `VerticalLayout` set in its `setCompositionRoot()` method and some Labels and other layouts are set within that `VerticalLayout`. Implementing my custom component in the main view class I would like to be able to handle clicks on my custom component, meaning the `VerticalLayout` as the composition root element:

```java
MyCustomComponent component = new MyCustomComponent();
component.addOnClickListener(listener);
```

But there is no method like `addOnClickListener` available. How can I implement that functionality? I know that I can handle a click on a layout with the `LayoutClickListener` within the custom component, but is there also a way that I can set the listener, where the component is declared, e.g. in the main view class (similar to the code snippet above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create your own method like you named addOnClickListener, that take as a parameter LayoutClickListener . Inside the implementation of addOnClickListener you add the listener to your layout. Example:

```
component.addOnClickListener(new LayoutClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void layoutClick(LayoutClickEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

and the implementation of component.addOnClickListener:

```
public void addOnClickListener(LayoutClickListener listener){
    yourVerticalLayout.addLayoutClickListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Don't know why I couldn't figure that out myself.

Comment: sometimes we need some hint ;)